# How to get cost for new g suite licenses?

Tags: gmail, google-apps, google-workspace, google-reseller-api

I am a G Suite Reseller and I need to create a website where my clients can enter the number of g suite users/licenses they want to add and it will calculate the price for them based on the number of licenses and the remaining period.

I have already searched the reseller API page but didn't find any useful resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need the re-seller API for that, you can check the G Suite licenses price at gsuite.google.com you can just create your own page and calculate it based on those prices,the re-seller API works just to manage the subscription of your clients but nothing related to billing all the reference about the reseller API can be found here https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/reference/.

Now if you want to retrieve the expiration date for the plan then you can use the Rseller API,[Reseller API > Subscriptions](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/reference/subscriptions) you will find the JSON with the plan start and end time, I would say you can use them to .

"plan": {
    "planName": string,
    "isCommitmentPlan": boolean,
    "commitmentInterval": {
      "startTime": long,
      "endTime": long
    }

I don't have a reseller account but I would say that the best option is to use the [Subscriptions > Get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/reference/subscriptions/get) to retreive the start and endtime from the plan. The methods I found are

1. Plan 'startTime plan.commitmentInterval.startTime', an annual commitment plan's interval's startTime in milliseconds using UNIX Epoch format
2. Plan 'endtTime plan.commitmentInterval.endTime', an annual commitment plan's interval's endTime in milliseconds using the UNIX Epoch format.(for more information about the UNIX Epoch format check the subscription overview property names)

What I am not sure since I dont have how to test is if these two are linked to an annual plan or can be used to any other plan. I hope this information can be of help, greetings.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I'm afraid I did not clarify my question properly. I need to extract the expiration date of the subscription in order to quote the client for the additional users. Example: a client requests 2 additional users to his account, and his/her subscription ends after 3 months. I need to extract the expiration date using the API in order to automatically quote the client accordingly.  What do you think?

Comment: I just updated my answer, I hope that information can be of help. I don't have a test account but you can try, I hope it works.

Comment: I believe this answers my question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you are welcome, please consider upvote or accept it as an answer. Greetings